# Display Int or Double Widget Equivalent to Text()?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to display a double (or int) similar to how you would a string with a `Text()` widget. Is there an equivalent to this widget for ints or doubles in Flutter? Sorry if this is obvious, but I could not find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Text("${<Your double/int variable>"})
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

You use a `Text` widget for this as well, simply use string interpolation to display your variables as a `String`:

```dart
final int two = 2;
final double pi = 3.14;

return Text("$two is an integer, and $pi is a double.");
```

You can also use the `toString()` method on any object in Dart (which is what the string interpolation above does implicitly). So if you want to print a double by itself, it's possible to write:

```dart
Text(pi.toString());
```

[More on Strings and interpolation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#strings)